# orbeon xform repeating element issue

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I am trying to add one repeating element on the fly/run time using the add button . When i click the add button i get the error 
"Function index uses repeat id 'employee-repeat' which is not in scope"  . I am not sure if i am referring the repeating element properly within the form. here is the complete x from .

```
      `<xhtml:html xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:xxforms="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
        xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
        xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude"
        xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql"
        xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
        xmlns:exforms="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
        xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events">
<xhtml:head>
    <xhtml:title>U Form</xhtml:title>
    <xforms:model id="fr-form-model">
       <xforms:instance id="fr-form-instance">
            <form>
                <section-1>
                    <hello/>
                </section-1>
            </form>
        </xforms:instance>


        <xforms:bind id="fr-form-binds" nodeset="instance('fr-form-instance')">
            <xforms:bind id="section-1-bind" nodeset="section-1">
                <xforms:bind id="hello-bind" nodeset="hello" name="hello"/>
            </xforms:bind>
        </xforms:bind>


        <xforms:instance id="fr-form-metadata" xxforms:readonly="true">
            <metadata>
                <application-name>gvhd</application-name>
                <form-name>test</form-name>
                <title xml:lang="en">Untitled Form</title>
                <description xml:lang="en"/>
                <author/>
                <logo mediatype="" filename="" size=""/>
            </metadata>
        </xforms:instance>


        <xforms:instance id="fr-form-attachments">
            <attachments>
                <css mediatype="text/css" filename="" size=""/>
                <pdf mediatype="application/pdf" filename="" size=""/>
            </attachments>
        </xforms:instance>


        <xforms:instance id="fr-form-resources" xxforms:readonly="true">
            <resources>
                <resource xml:lang="en">
                    <section-1>
                        <label>Section1</label>
                        <help/>
                    </section-1>
                    <hello>
                        <label>hello</label>
                        <hint/>
                        <help/>
                        <alert/>
                    </hello>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </xforms:instance>

        <xforms:instance id="employees-instance">
            <employees>
                <employee>
                    <first-name>Alice</first-name>
                </employee>
                <employee>
                    <first-name>Bob</first-name>
                </employee>
                <employee>
                    <first-name>Marie</first-name>
                </employee>
            </employees>
        </xforms:instance>


        <xforms:instance id="fr-service-request-instance" xxforms:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <request/>
        </xforms:instance>

        <xforms:instance id="fr-service-response-instance" xxforms:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <response/>
        </xforms:instance>

    </xforms:model>
</xhtml:head>
<xhtml:body>
    <fr:view>
        <xforms:label ref="instance('fr-form-metadata')/title"/>
        <fr:body>
            <fr:section id="section-1-section" bind="section-1-bind">
                <xforms:label ref="$form-resources/section-1/label"/>
                <xforms:help ref="$form-resources/section-1/help"/>
                <fr:grid columns="2">
                    <xforms:repeat nodeset="instance('employees-instance')/employee" id="employee-repeat">
                              <xhtml:tr>
                            <xhtml:td>
                                <xforms:output ref="first-name"/>
                            </xhtml:td>
                            <xhtml:td>
                                <xforms:output ref="first-name"/>
                            </xhtml:td>
                        </xhtml:tr>
                                                  </xforms:repeat>
                    <xhtml:tr>
                        <xhtml:td>
                            <xforms:input bind="hello-bind" id="hello-control">
                                <xforms:label ref="$form-resources/hello/label"/>
                                <xforms:hint ref="$form-resources/hello/hint"/>
                                <xforms:help ref="$form-resources/hello/help"/>
                                <xforms:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                            </xforms:input>
                        </xhtml:td>
                        <xhtml:td/>
                    </xhtml:tr>
                    <xhtml:tr>
                        <xhtml:td>
                            <xforms:trigger>
                                <xforms:label>Add</xforms:label>
                                <xforms:insert ev:event="DOMActivate" context="instance('fr-form-instance')" nodeset="instance('employees-instance')/employee" at="index('employee-repeat')"
                                               position="after"/>
                            </xforms:trigger>
                        </xhtml:td>
                        <xhtml:td/>
                    </xhtml:tr>
                </fr:grid>
            </fr:section>
        </fr:body>
    </fr:view>
</xhtml:body>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I have run this code in Orbeon Sandbox and could not reproduce the mentioned error. I had few errors related to variable not declared, Once i declared the variables, the form rendered normally and i was able to Add new rows.

However, technically i see that you are using the repeat index `index('employee-repeat')` in the Add trigger which is outside of the repeat loop and hence you might have got that error. To help better, let me know how you run the forms.

**Update:** Based on the OP comment, here is the update.

Its easy to correct it. You should not use `index('employee-repeat')`.

1. If you want to add the new row in the last use `at=last()` or
2. If you want to add in the first use `at=1` or
3. If you want to add in the middle( your desired position) then move
   the `Add` link inside the repeat and for each row, you will have
   `Add` link to add a new row at desired position.

Comment: I run the form on the orbeon form builder . save it as new from and run it as new form . I know Something is wrong with at="index('employee-repeat')" not sure how to correct it .

Comment: @KripalSingh : Hi Kripal, I have updated answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your example seems to work fine with the latest Orbeon Forms code. It runs without errors, and "Marie Marie" gets added when pressing the *Add* button. Have you tried this with [Orbeon Forms 4.0 M10](http://blog.orbeon.com/2012/08/orbeon-forms-40-m10.html)?

(Note that 4.0 M10 is a *milestone build*, which is not yet a 4.0 final release.)

Comment: Yes, I tried the code in Orbeon 3.9 CE Sandbox which worked fine.

Comment: i am running this on dev-post-3.7.1.200910140016

Comment: @KripalSingh Sorry, but this is a really, really old version, and I am afraid I won't be able to help you with this here. If at all possible, you should consider upgrading Orbeon Forms. (And since we're getting closer to a 4.0 release, maybe you could even use a 4.0 milestone build.)

Answer (score 0):

As per the Original XF 1.1 recommendation mr Kaipa M Sarma statement is correct , once u decided to use the trigger button outside the repeat control , mention the corresponding index like last() , or index = 1 . Otherwise if u need to insert in the middle or whatever location u decide use button inside the repeat ..